# How to convert this recursion into a loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, recursion

I am thinking about this question, say I have a recursion version of a power function:

```
double pow(double base, int power){
    if(power == 1 || power == 0){
        return base;
    }
    else if(power % 2 == 0){ 
        double result = pow(base,power/2);
        return result * result;
    }
    else{
        double result = pow(base,(power-1)/2);
        return result * result * base;
    }

}
```

My question is that how can I convert this one into a while loop?

EDIT: I know this can be done by explicitly maintain a stack, but in this special case is there any chance not doing that?

Comment: @devnull I am a TA and got asked the question, but do not know how to answer

Comment: that's also not really tail recursion, in that the optimizations granted by tail recursion are not applicable in this case. With the edit it definately isn't tail recursion.

Comment: @Dan Edit it and moved out the tail recursion bit

Comment: Do correct your code: if `power==0` then your function should return `1` not `base`.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but this seems like it would be trivial to implement with a loop.  Or am I missing some "gotcha?"

Comment: @SeanBright Can you post your answer? maybe it is me being stupid here

Comment: @haccks why is that the case?

Comment: @dorafmon; See this: http://ideone.com/Fwottc

Comment: @dorafmon `I am a TA and got asked the question, but do not know how to answer` -- I have full sympathy for your students.

Comment: @haccks the function name is identical to a parameter, change one of them and it will compile.

Comment: @Wimmel; I know. That's why I wonder he is asked a wrong code to work with!!

Comment: @haccks sorry about the mistake I did not compile it before I post it. I thought you can get the idea :( Deeply sorry

Comment: @devnull Yeah I do that too, I will try to be better next time

Comment: I don't get why this is on hold, for the reason "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." I am sure I know what I am asking, and I know the expected answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's the exponentiation by squaring algorithm.

Here's how you'd do it iteratively:

```
double pow(double base, int power)
{
    double result = 1;

    while (power != 0)
    {
        if (power % 2 == 1)
            result *= base;

        power /= 2;    
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't modify function parameters can you? And this doesn't work with negative powers yo.

Comment: @nevercode I don't see any restriction regarding the modification of the parameters.

Comment: @nevercode yes you can, unless you declare them `const`.

Comment: My bad, I thought you couldn't.

Comment: @nevercode Some people suggest that it's bad form to reassign parameters; I think some discretion needs to be used, but in some cases it's fine. Here, as we're mimicking recursion, I think it makes more sense to alter the parameters than to use a second set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
double power(double base, int power){
    if(power == 1){
        return base;
    }

    if (power == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }     
    int absolutePower = abs(power);
    double result = 1;  
    for (int i = 0; i < absolutePower; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }      
    if (power < 0)
    {
        result = 1/result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this is not the same algorithm, it does not optimize `power(2,4)` into `power(power(2,2),2)`

Comment: You are right. Didn't notice I had to use the same algorithm.